# Inkscape export to PNG not showing background with high resolution

Tags: inkscape, svg, export, png

I am trying to export a .svg file to .png with Inkscape. The original .svg file was created with the prettymaps python toolbox (https://github.com/marceloprates/prettymaps) which creates .svg images of a map for given coordinates.

In the .svg image there is a background of continuous little dots. However, when exporting certain parts of the image with a setting of more than (roughly) 160 dpi, the background always gets deleted and is not rendered at all.

Here is an example of how the image should look like (this is a .png export with a setting of 150dpi):

[image]

And here is the same part of the image when exported with a slightly higher dpi of 180:

[image]

Other parts of the image work fine (e.g. the top left corner) even with higher resolutions but some parts always cause this problem

What am I doing wrong? Or rather: What in the image is causing this problem?

Edit: I upload an example file here:
dropbox.com/s/4rcctpb6djjhua6/Background_Image.svg?dl=0
This can be exported in Inkscape to give the described results. I.e. when using a dpi of 150 the background is there and when using 180 it is not there. When using a custom area, I can for example choose x0 = 0, x1 = 2000, y0 = 0, y1= 800. Here using a dpi of 180 works fine. When changing x0 = 2000 and x1 = 2300, a dpi of 180 does not work anymore.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you share the SVG file?  Sorry but it's almost impossible to say what's wrong without access to the SVG.  Share it on svgshare.com and post the link here. Also what settings are you using?  Are you using export Page, Drawing, Selection, Custom? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the background is there. But its transparent

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks for the hints. I tried svgshare but it didn't work so I uploaded it to Dropbox instead:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4rcctpb6djjhua6/Background_Image.svg?dl=0
To reduce size, I deleted all elements except for the background that causes problems. The behaviour is still the same. In Inkscape, I use export Page (I tried the other ones as well, same behaviour) and just set dpi to 180 or 150 respectively and then press Export. I don't change Advanced settings or anything

Comment: @user149206 -  I suspect the software you used to create this is the problem, not Inkscape. It's a pattern made of multiple clones, and it's huge. I can't really understand why it is so huge to be honest, something to do with how it was constructed. Inkscape just doesn't like it at all.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you for your feedback! I see what you mean and I can't tell you more details about why it was created that way, either. I guess what confuses me still is that it seems to work fine on most parts of the pattern but not on some specific areas. Even though I would expect this pattern to be the same everywhere.

Comment: I tried making a similar pattern of small dots natively in Inkscape, and exporting as a PNG works fine, however if the dots are smaller than a pixel, they won't be visible in the exported render.  Also, the pattern I created is a fraction of the size of your example. Only abut 4kb.  Your example SVG is over 1.4MB

Comment: See [Example Inkscape SVG](https://svgshare.com/i/b5D.svg) that I made - the dots are actually so small they don't even render properly in a browser even when I zoom in all the way. But the file size is tiny.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you! I suppose my best bet is then to replace my pattern with a new one that has bigger dots

Comment: I suppose it's the known pattern bug where a pattern origin that is far away from the object it applies to exceeds the available numeric length and thus is not drawn.

Move the pattern origin closer to your object to solve the problem. In some cases, this still doesn't work, you can subscribe to this report here: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/927#note_699602439